# Is this constraint holonomic or non-holonomic?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, constrained-dynamics

$$f(q,q^\prime, t) = 0, ~\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial q}~\mathrm dq + \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^\prime}~\mathrm dq^\prime+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}~\mathrm dt = 0$$

I really want to know whether this constraint is [holonomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) or non-holonomic.

(As far as I know, Non-holonomic constraint has a term of velocity and do non-integrable. But this formula does not dependent on a path, because it is a total differential form.)

- prime is a time derivative.

Comment: Is prime a time derivative?

Comment: yes, it is a time derivative. q and q' are dependent variable of time

Answer (score 3):

1. Firstly, recall that [virtual displacements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) don't change time $\delta t=0$. Time is fixed, say $t=t_0$.
2. Secondly, let $M$ be the position space, often call the [configuration space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space), with [generalized position coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $q^i$.
3. OP is right that the constraint $\delta f(q,v,t) \approx 0$ doesn't depend on virtual displacements $(\delta q,\delta v)$ in the tangent bundle $TM$ (with appropriate boundary conditions imposed). However, a velocity-dependent constraint $f(q,v,t) \approx 0$ is not well-defined on the position manifold $M$ itself. And it is down in the base manifold $M$ where the applications, such as, e.g., [d'Alembert's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_principle) take place.
4. TL;DR: A [holonomic constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) has by definition no velocity dependence.

Comment: There's nothing in here that says the constraint has velocity dependence. For all we know, $df/dq'=0$. (Also, isn't f(q, q', t) just the form of a 1-D functional?)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is defined such that $f=0$ at all points, then it is a holonomic constraint. One example is this:

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2=0$

which constrains motion to the surface of a sphere of radius $r$.